# Check if a particular column of the table is empty in python where the entire table content is stored in a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a table that looks like:

```
         id  ConsumerID                                    StoredFileLinks                                           Response  ... Active Archived CreatedDate         UpdatedDate
0     14663         264                                                 []  {"success": true, "message": "Device has passe...  ...      1        0        None 2019-11-14 10:54:56
1     14662         264                                                 []  {"success": true, "message": "Device detected ...  ...      1        0        None 2019-11-14 10:54:22
2     14661         264                                                 []  {"success": true, "message": "Device has passe...  ...      1        0        None 2019-11-14 10:53:01
3     14660       22918                                                 []  {"success": true, "message": "Device has passe...  ...      1        0        None 2019-11-14 09:27:15
4     14658       22918                                                 []  {"success": true, "message": "Device detected ...  ...      1        0        None 2019-11-14 09:20:05
5     14656          -5                                                 []  {"success": true, "message": "Device detected ...  ...      1        0        None 2019-11-14 08:20:29
6     14655          -5  [{"OriginalImage": "s3://crackd/inference_v2/I...  {"success": true, "message": "Device detected ...  ...      1        0        None 2019-11-14 08:13:46
7     14654         100  [{"OriginalImage": "s3://crackd/inference_v2/T...  {"success": true, "message": "Device has passe...  ...      1        0        None 2019-11-14 07:16:49
8     14652         100  [{"OriginalImage": "s3://crackd/inference_v2/S...  {"success": true, "message": "Device has passe...  ...      1        0        None 2019-11-14 06:47:46
9     14651         100  [{"OriginalImage": "s3://crackd/inference_v2/Y...  {"success": true, "message": "Device has passe...  ...      1        0        None 2019-11-14 06:47:00
10    14644           1  [{"OriginalImage": "s3://crackd/inference_v2/F...  {"success": true, "message": "Device has passe...  ...      1        0        None 2019-11-14 04:53:33
11    14641           1  [{"OriginalImage": "s3://crackd/inference_v2/D...  {"success": true, "message": "Device has passe...  ...      1        0        None 2019-11-14 04:50:53
```

These table contents have been fetched using MySQL query from a python function that returns the variable named **table_contents** containing the above table contents. (variable type is: **class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'** )

Now I want only those rows of **table_contents** to be stored in the dictionary provided the StoredFileLinks column is not an empty list.

My attempt:

```
response_object = {
    'table_result': []
}

for i in table_contents:
    if i['StoredFileLinks'] is not None:
        response_object['table_result'] = table_contents[i]
```

Error:

```
    if i['StoredFileLinks'] is not None:
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

How to tackle this? Sorry coz I'm new to handling pandas dataframe objects.

PS: on Printing the variable i, I'm getting only the column names of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why these methods weren't working in my case. Have just verified their correctness and indeed they are.

Maybe the column StoredFileLinks was of the type class '**pandas.core.series.Series**' and the data is complex enough for pandas to act on it.

So the alternate approach I followed was modifying the MySQL query itself..

As MySQL stores data in String format, so I modified my query to look like:

```
Select * from *table_name* where StoredFileLinks != '[]' and ...;
```

Answer (score 2):

If convert empty lists to boolean get `False`, so you can filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with casting to `bool`s:

```
table_contents = pd.DataFrame({'StoredFileLinks':[[],[],[{'a':'b'}]]})
print (table_contents)
  StoredFileLinks
0              []
1              []
2    [{'a': 'b'}]

table_contents = table_contents[table_contents.StoredFileLinks.astype(bool)]
print (table_contents)
  StoredFileLinks
2    [{'a': 'b'}]
```

Solution with lenghts tested by [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html):

```
table_contents = table_contents[table_contents.StoredFileLinks.str.len() != 0]
print (table_contents)
  StoredFileLinks
2    [{'a': 'b'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
table_contents = table_contents[table_contents.StoredFileLinks.map(len) > 0]
```